# Paypal error message "Capture amount exceeds allowable limit"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We wrote the below function in sandbox environment

```
function captureTransactions(access_token, d) {
try {
    var req = http.request("POST", _config.host + "/v1/payments/authorization/" + d.authorization_id + "/capture", JSON.stringify({
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": d.total
        },
        "is_final_capture": true
    }), {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    });

    var r = JSON.parse(req.readAll().toString());
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e.stack);
    console.error(r);
}

console.warn("[captureTransactions]", r);

return r;
};
```

and receive the below error

```
{
  "name": "CAPTURE_AMOUNT_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
  "message": "Capture amount exceeds allowable limit.",
  "information_link":     "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#CAPTURE_AMOUNT_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
  "debug_id": "2fc79fc7df623"
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for receiving this msg and how to fix it? Note that we only test $5 payments so it shouldn't be due to transaction size. We did do multiple authorizations on the same card before, but not sure if that could be the reason for this error?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You must be trying to capture more than was authorized..??

Comment: send your full request without creds

Comment: issue solved - sandbox was down for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem on the live site with PayFlow today. It appears that you cannot use a "Credit Card" that is "Attached" to that "Gateway" account with "PayPal".

I supposed that is a method to stop "Customers" (**PayPal payment service users**) from "Paying" themselves as a ***Paypal employee*** explained to me on another separate issue. That is where we were testing a Billing Software with the gateway and refunding the money back to our account after the transaction. We were told that we could put our own money into our account(s) that way. At the time "I ask how we were to pay the $60.00 monthly fee if the business (PayPal account) hasn't collected/processed any money yet if we can't put money in there? This was resolved by the 1st part of this Answer.